# reading ID3 tag in NativeScript + Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, fs, id3

I am trying to read id3 tags of mp3 files in my project but it seems all the node plugins has a dependency on `fs` , 
since I get this error: `TypeError: fs.exists is not a function`

so How can I read id3 tags in NativeScript?

Comment: **{N} !== Node**, you will have to fetch the meta data in native iOS / Android way. Give a try for [nativescript-media-metadata-retriever](https://github.com/VedantMistry13/nativescript-media-metadata-retriever) plugin.

Comment: it seems that nativescript-media-metadata-retriever needs Angular Plugin, is there any plugin that works with Vue and will not required Angular?

Comment: May be you misunderstood, did you actually try the plugin? The author just gives example with Angular as he might be a Angular user. The plugin is common for all flavor / framework.

Comment: I thought for lunching, it needs the Angular Component! my bads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**{N} !== Node**, You will have to fetch the meta data in native iOS / Android way. Use [nativescript-media-metadata-retriever](https://github.com/VedantMistry13/nativescript-media-metadata-retriever) plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-media-metadata-retriever
```

Comment: It works very good, thanks a lot, do you know How can I keep it silent? it logs too many info, i mean this things :  `[nativescript-media-metadata-retriever]: Data source has been set...' JS: '[nativescript-media-metadata-retriever]: All metadata extracted...' JS: '[nativescript-media-metadata-retriever]: Failed to generate bitmap...`

Comment: How can I save coverAlbum, in SDCARD? I get it by : `mmr.getEmbeddedPicture().then( ( args ) => {...} )` , but I dont Know how can I save the `args` as a File.

Comment: I tried to save it by: `let source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
                                source.fromAsset( args )
                                .then( ( imageSource ) => {...})` but it says: `TypeError: asset.getImageAsync is not a function`

Comment: The return value from `getEmbeddedPicture()` is not a `ImageAsset` but a native source. Use `fromNativeSource` instead of `fromAsset`. Everything is well documented, read plugin's read me and {N} docs carefully.

Comment: I just found the Module [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/image-source#image-source), and there is not mentioned about `fromNativeSource` could you please share the link please?

Comment: and now I get this one: `TypeError: source.fromNativeSource is not a function`

Comment: Refer the [class definition of ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [nativescript-nodeify](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify), but I remember having problem afterwards with with [bundling](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack).

Also, I used this back in NativeScript 4. I don't know if this still works in NS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I share my usage of this module in sake of noobies like me, who can waste their times just for a misunderstanding  :))

requires:

```
import { MediaMetadataRetriever } from "nativescript-media-metadata-retriever";
const imageSourceModule = require( "tns-core-modules/image-source" ); 
const fs = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");
```

and the code:

```
// ------- init MediaMetadataRetriever         
let mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource( newValue );
mmr.getEmbeddedPicture()
.then( ( args ) => {

    // ------- show the albumArt on bgIMG
    var albumArt = this.$refs.bgIMG.nativeView; 
    var img = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
    // ------- setNativeSource is a **Methods** of imageSourceModule
    img.setNativeSource( args );
    albumArt.set( "src" , img );
    console.log("ImageSource set...");

    // ------- save the albumArt in root of SDCARD
    // ------- fromNativeSource is a **Function** of imageSourceModule
    let imageSource = imageSourceModule.fromNativeSource( args );
    console.log("Here");
    let fileName = "test.png";
    const root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
    let path = fs.path.join( root , fileName);
    let saved = imageSource.saveToFile(path, "png");
    if (saved) {
        console.log("Image saved successfully!");
    }

} );
```